# getting windows username instead of logged in user name in asp .net web form 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

Web Config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Public/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="default.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
```

Loggin Code:

```
if (userLoginResults.UserLoginStatus == UserLoginStatus.Successful)
        {
            var email = UserName.Text.ToLower().Trim();

            if (userLoginResults.Contains(UserRoleNames.Admin))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(email, RememberMe.Checked);
                Session["isMemberLoggedIn"] = true;
                Response.Redirect("~/AdminPanel/Default.aspx");
            }
```

}

//
 var email = User.Identity.Name;

I did login by admin@admin.com  but i am getting DESKTOP-OPT261T\mobasshir. this is my windows username..
How can i solve this?

I am using windows 10. microsoft visual studio professional 2013

Thanks all

Comment: What code is returning "DESKTOP-OPT261T\mobasshir"?  Can you post that?  The UserName textbox above should be admin@admin.com...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I have fixed it by disable the windows authentication... i did it by clicking on webproject from visual studio and then pressed f4 then  windows authentication to disbled